# MVC4 areas and forms authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I have an MVC4 application set up with multiple areas. Each area must have its own login page. Let's say for example I have the following areas:

Main
Admin

How can I set it so that the "Main" area has a different login page to the "Admin" area? I'm thinking web.config is not the way to go on this.

Currently I have the following in my root web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Admin/Login" timeout="2880" protection="Encryption" />
</authentication>
```

However, I'm struggling to work out how to adapt this to MVC4 with areas.

Please help.

Comment: I don't know it can be done with web.config. If you can't make it work you can always write your own action filter deriving from System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute and override HandleUnauthorizedRequest method.

Comment: Do you have any links where this can be hooked up with multiple areas?

Comment: I will post an example.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? You can add as many login pages as you want to your application regardless of where they are located in the solution. Your login logic will set up the credentials in a cookie and you should be able to access them from any Area.

Comment: @lopezbertoni He has specific a login page for each area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many thanks to Ufuk Hacıoğulları for putting me on the right scent. My final solution was this:

```
public class AreaAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly string area;

    public AreaAuthorizeAttribute(string area)
    {
        this.area = area;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        string loginUrl = "";

        if (area == "Admin")
        {
            loginUrl = "~/Admin/Login";
        }
        else if (area == "Members")
        {
            loginUrl = "~/Members/Login";
        }

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(loginUrl + "?returnUrl=" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if you can make it work with configuration files in each folder. Use that solution if you can. If you can't, here's a custom action filter that you can use:

```
public class AreaAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        string area = filterContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("area") 
                        ? filterContext.RouteData.Values["area"].ToString()
                        : null;

        if (area == "Admin")
        {
            RouteValueDictionary routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary 
            {
                {"controller" , "Login"},
                {"action" , "Index"},
                {"area" , "Admin"}
             };

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("AdminAreaRoute", routeValues);
        }
        else if (area == "User")
        {
            RouteValueDictionary routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary 
            {
                {"controller" , "Login"},
                {"action" , "Index"},
                {"area" , "User"}
            };

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("UserAreaRoute", routeValues);
        }

        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

You may need to fix route names, I can't remember if ASP.NET MVC generated a route for each area. Then you can use it like this:

```
[AreaAuthorize]
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I have that code in place, and it by default wants to use Windows authentication, since it's popping up a browser authentication request. If I add <authentication mode="Forms" /> into the root web.config, then it always bounces to login.aspx, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @LaurenceFrost Did you choose Intranet project template when creating the project?

Comment: Many thanks for your assistance - you will see my final solution below.