# Login Page not showing for unauthenticated user (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I'm trying to redirect users to my login page if they're aren't logged in. Using areas in mvc, I have an Admin area which holds the login view.

In the root web config i set the authentication mode to forms and the url to point to the login.cshtml in the Admin area. The browser show default aunthorised page, instead of redirecting to login page.

**Root Web Config**

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Areas/Admin/Views/Account/Login" />
    </authentication>
 </system.web>
```

Comment: this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424704/mvc4-areas-and-forms-authentication