# How to set authorize for Areas in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, asp.net-identity, authorize-attribute

I create a Admin Areas. I want that before access to Admin/Home/Index, you have to login at Admin/Account/Login. So, i set authorize for HomeController. Cause I'm using Asp.net Identity, so to be able to turn to Admin/Account/Login, i set on LoginPath = new PathString("/Admin/Account/Login") in StartUp.Auth.cs file.

But now, If i set Authorize for Controller on Client side, it'll be redirected to Admin/Account/Login

How to separate 2 way to authorize in one project.

Thanks so much for kind helping.

PS: I also try this but it's still doesn't work for me
[MVC4 areas and forms authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424704/mvc4-areas-and-forms-authentication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I totally understand what you are trying to do but I guess you want to redirect users to different Index page once logged-in?
If so you have several options:
Assuming your are using the Identity Model shipped in with MVC5:

1 - In your **AccountController** - **Login Action** (HttpPost)

After ***var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync....***
Add something like that :

- var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
- returnUrl = UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Admin")? "/Admin/Home" :
  returnUrl;

2- Or you can create a customer **ActionFilterAttribute** like this one (simplified for demo purpose but yet working example):

```
public class RedirectLoginFilter:ActionFilterAttribute
{
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // First check if authentication succeed and user authenticated:            

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {                
            bool IsAdmin = filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin");

            //Then check for user role(s) and assign view accordingly, don't forget the 
            //[Authorize(Roles = "YourRoleHere")] on your controller / action
            if (IsAdmin)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
                (new
                {
                    area = "Admin",
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index"
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
                (new
                {
                    area = "",
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index"
                }));
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
```

Now in your default **returnUrl** Controller Action for all non-identificated users ie: **Home/Index** add your custom filterActionAttribute :

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [RedirectLoginFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {                        
        return View();            
    }
```

Bear in mind that with the last solution everytime your will try to access your Home/Index method with admin role you will be redirected to the admin Index page.

Comment: I wil try your explain. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

You can always do a check in the navigation area if the user is in a specific role and authenticated and choose to show / hide those specific areas if they are not. First you would want to put the [Authorize] decorator on any controllers necessary, then you can do this in your cshtml files to make sure only admins can see the admin areas.

```
 @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Admin", "Account")</li>              
                }
            }
```